# is the fix function a better way to replace while loops?

Tags: haskell, recursion

When you are in a do block, in order to emulate a "while loop" it's common to see people declaring a "loop" function in a let statement. however, there is this clever function "fix" which allows you to declare and use the function at the same time

```
main = do
   let fac n r = if n == 1 then r else fact (n-1) (n*r)
   print $ fact 4 1 -- 24
   
   print $ fix (\rec n r -> if n == 1 then r else rec (n-1) (n*r)) 4 1
```

the question is, does fix have any advantage over using a let statement?
is slower or uses more memory?

Comment: I vaguely recall reading somewhere that GHC does a better job of optimizing non-recursive functions than recursive functions. ("Recursive" here being a reference to its static properties; the argument to `fix` is itself not recursive because it calls whatever function is passed as its first argument, which isn't necessarily itself.)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no advantage. It's even implemented as a `let` expression:

```
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

Comment: Doesn't it open the opportunity for some inlining? Not sure if the overall cost would be better.

Comment: @pedrofurla I'm not sure what you mean. Could you expand a bit? In particular, I don't see how `fix` could open an opportunity for inlining that `let` couldn't open, given that, as mentioned in the answer, `fix` *is* a `let`.

Comment: As further confirmation, if you compile the example code in the original question with `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all`, GHC merges both versions into a single value/definition `main2`, which is simply printed twice.